# Can Google Sheets retrieve data from an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can a Google Spreadsheet retrieve data from Excel? I need to update some cells in a google spreadsheet using information present in an excel document. Based on what I already have, it would be good if I could convert the data from a column in the excel document into an array and use that. I don't have the excel document in a google drive and would only like to do so if it can be automated and deleted after.

Thanks!

Comment: You could create a csv of your data and load that into a google sheet with Utilities.parseCsv()

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That does look like a good option thank you. How would I go about searching for the csv file though when its created locally?

Comment: In Apps Script? You can't. Google Apps Script is cloud-based and so can't access your local files at all. You'd need to use a [Drive API client library](https://developers.google.com/drive) or upload the file via the Drive UI and then convert it in Apps Script from there.

Comment: Would there happen to be a way to do it with VBA?

Comment: Offline? You might be able to integrate it with the Google API using the .NET framework client library ([quickstart here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet), [uploading media documentation here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload), [Google Drive documentation for C# here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/))

Comment: Well it can be online and ideally I'd want to avoid the need to download google API at all. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Google sheets api is a standard rest api. I assume you could make  standard http calls with vba along with oauth?

Comment: I'm sorry but what you're saying makes no sense to me. This is probably a little out of my depth.

Comment: You can make the csv with VBA and put it on DropBox and get it from DropBox with Google Apps Script.